# Stripe, token is not generated on Live Server, on Local works fine

Tags: stripe-payments

as title i have a weird problem. I've tried to integrate Stripe payment gateway to my website, but the problem is token is not generated on Live Server while on Local Machine it works just fine...

My code:

```html
/*index.php*/
<?php
  require_once('config.php');
?>

<form action="charge.php" method="post">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-description="Access for a year"
          data-amount="5000"
          data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

```html
/*config.php*/

<?php
  require_once('stripe/init.php');

  $stripe = array(
    "secret_key"      => "sk_test_lcnCLz5lnSWPzhMRMOhjGcXD",
    "publishable_key" => "pk_test_KW35E5D3ShuLfvd60VHrRVJQ"
  );

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

```html
/*charge.php*/

<?php
  require_once('config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in your server logs?

Comment: Okay i figured it out i had to remove .php because my htaccess remove it by default and the page simply reloaded, so no token was set. ;)